# Constr is not a constructor Magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript

I simply want to add js for my custom module but I'm getting this error:

> layout.js:137 Uncaught TypeError: Constr is not a constructor

The hello.js file will still work, console.log will still work, however, I still get the error above. Any idea?

requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        emlhello          : 'EML_CityAutocomplete/js/hello'
    }
}};
```

hello.js

```
define([
    "jquery"
], function($){
    "use strict";
    console.log('asdasd');
   return true;
})
```

And I'm trying to call it via layout xml

```
<referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="autocomplete" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">EML_CityAutocomplete/js/hello</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Comment: Have you check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117007/magento2-getting-constr-is-not-a-constructor-error-for-custom-theme ?

Comment: I'm certain that I'm using define instead of require, and I'm certain that module-checkout-agreement has nothing to do with it as the error won't show up if I disable the module.

Upon doing some trial and error, it seems that i has something to do with
<item name="autocomplete" xsi:type="array">
For some reason "autocomplete" does not exist and I'm not sure on how to declare it.