# Magento 2: why price textbox dissappeared from add product?

Tags: magento2, admin, price

Why the price box is not there?

please check the following image

[image]

in the console I get this error message:

```
TypeError: Constr is not a constructor[Learn More] layout.js:137:25
initComponent http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/core/renderer/layout.js:137:25
fire http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3232:12
fireWith http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3362:8
Deferred/</deferred[tuple[0]] http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3461:6
fire http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3232:12
fireWith http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3362:8
Deferred/</deferred[tuple[0]] http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/jquery.js:3461:6
loadSource/< http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/core/renderer/layout.js:120:13
execCb http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1650:24
context.execCb http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/mage/requirejs/resolver.js:145:24
check http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:866:43
enable/</< http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1113:29
bind/< http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:132:20
emit/< http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1156:21
each http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:57:31
emit http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1155:17
check http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:917:25
enable http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1143:17
init http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:774:21
callGetModule http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1170:17
completeLoad http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1564:25
onScriptLoad http://localhost/pub/static/version1540020473/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs/require.js:1671:21
```

Comment: did you checked console(inspect element) and var/log folder?

Comment: the question is updated with the error message.

Comment: check [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117007/magento2-getting-constr-is-not-a-constructor-error-for-custom-theme) or this [one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/242653/constr-is-not-a-constructor-on-layout-js-line-137-error-custom-module?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: but most of these posts includes custom js code that was written by the user with mistakes, I have a fresh copy of magento. anyway I tried to run "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" and it worked for me. thank you...